# Ordering of factors . ggplot2 vs plyr, problems fixing label position to barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr

I'm trying to plot a stacked boxplot with labels on the box segments.
But the ordering imposed by the factor variables, which ggplot2 recognises and plots by the ordering, plyr do not seem to respect this ordering, and trying to force an ordering by order.by gives missing values, might be cause of the formula.

[image: Image of the effect on label placement cause of diretent ordering]

```
pos = order_by(Segment, 1-((cumsum(antal) - (0.5 * antal))/sum(antal) ) )
```

If I change the factor 1000+ to 999 the expected result is as expected cause of the lexicographical ordering

Data and code to reproduce

```
tblVector_Value  <-  structure(list(antal = c(190L, 21L, 33L, 18L, 241L, 77L,102L, 42L, 45L, 32L), 
last_Year = c(2020L, 2021L, 2020L, 2021L, 2020L, 2021L, 2020L, 2021L, 2020L, 2021L), 
Segment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), 
.Label = c("0-100", "100-200", "1000+", "200-300", "300-400", "Error"),class = "factor")),
 .Names = c("antal", "last_Year", "Segment"), 
row.names = c(5L, 6L, 11L, 12L, 18L, 19L, 24L, 25L, 30L, 31L), 
class = "data.frame")

library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
## create factor    
tblVector_Value$Segment <-factor(tblVector_Value$Segment, c("0-100", "100-200","200-300","300-400", "1000+"))
tblVector_Value <- ddply(tblVector_Value, .(last_Year), transform, pos = 1-((cumsum(antal) - (0.5 * antal))/sum(antal) ))

ggplot(tblVector_Value[order(tblVector_Value$Segment, decreasing = T),],
aes(x=last_Year, y = antal,fill = Segment)) +
geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity") +
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) + labs(title="% segment") +
geom_text(aes(label = antal, y = pos), size = 3)
```

Comment: plyr and dplyr are two different packages. You might wish to re-title and re-tag this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the recent versions of `gplot2`, `geom_text()` places the labels correctly also for stacked and filled bar plots. So, if it is acceptable that the labels aren't placed exactly in the middle of the boxes it's not necessary to use `plyr` or whatever other packages for explicitely computing the positions.

```
tblVector_Value$Segment <- factor(tblVector_Value$Segment, 
                                  c("0-100", "100-200","200-300","300-400", "1000+"))
# turn last_Year into factor to avoid continuous x scale
tblVector_Value$last_Year <- factor(tblVector_Value$last_Year)

library(ggplot2)   # CRAN version 2.2.1 used
ggplot(tblVector_Value, aes(x = last_Year, y = antal, fill = Segment, label = antal)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) + labs(title="% segment") +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = "fill", vjust = 2)
```

[image]

Note that `vjust`can be used to fine-tune the placement of the text labels. Try `vjust = 1.5` or `vjust = 1.0`.

Comment: Thanks Uwe, you sure are cleaning up my R questions.